# Maven release: Developer information missing

Tags: maven

Getting this error on `mvn release:perform`

```
[ERROR] Repository "comconvertapi-1002" failures
[ERROR]   Rule "pom-staging" failures
[ERROR]     * Invalid POM: /com/convertapi/client/convertapi/1.7/convertapi-1.7.pom: Developer information missing
```

Releasing from branch: https://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-java/tree/feature/maven (could this error be related with that?)

This is POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.convertapi.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>convertapi</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <version>1.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ConvertAPI Java Client</name>
    <description>
        The ConvertAPI helps converting various file formats.
        Creating PDF and Images from various sources like Word, Excel, Powerpoint, images, web pages or raw HTML codes.
        Merge, Encrypt, Split, Repair and Decrypt PDF files.
        And many others files manipulations.
        In just few minutes you can integrate it into your application and use it easily.
        The ConvertAPI client library makes it easier to use the Convert API from your Java 8 projects without having to
        build your own API calls.
    </description>
    <url>https://www.convertapi.com/</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The MIT License</name>
            <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-java/master/LICENSE.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>jonas</id>
            <name>Jonas Jasas</name>
            <email>jonas@baltsoft.com</email>
            <organization>Baltsoft</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.baltsoft.com/</organizationUrl>
            <roles>
                <role>architect</role>
                <role>developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>+3</timezone>

            <properties>
                <picUrl>https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/16254748</picUrl>
            </properties>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-java.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-java.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-java</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/examples/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                    <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
                    <arguments>-Dgpg.passphrase=${gpg.passphrase}</arguments>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>


    <profiles>
        <!-- GPG Signature on release -->
        <profile>
            <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: The properties in the tag `<developer>` are wrong If i correctly remember...

Comment: The properties are allowed. Checked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seem ok, but sometime maven plugins use cache for some info.
Try to clear cache by this sequence of commands:

```
mvn clean
mvn release:prepare -Dresume=false
mvn release:perform
```

If it not helped, try to simplify developer section (excluding sequentially properties, timezone and so on)

Answer (score 0):

**Publish Requirement**
Please check you have fulfill all your [publish requirement.](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/)

- Supply Javadoc and Sources⚓︎
- Sign Files with GPG/PGP
- Sufficient Metadata
- Correct Coordinates
- Project Name, Description and URL
- License Information
- Developer Information
- SCM Information